# Cross-Compiling Qt for Embedded Linux Applications

Tags: c++, qt, debian, cross-compiling, beagleboneblack

Where qmake.conf file is located and how it should look for armhf debian wheezy platform? (BeagleBone Black)

I am trying to follow [these steps](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt-embedded-crosscompiling.html), but some of them are unreasonable like that one about qmake.

Also what does **export PATH=path/to/cross/compiler:$PATH** will do?

I enter something like this in path/to/cross/compiler

**export PATH=/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++:$PATH**

Comment: Some info about PATH [here](http://www.linfo.org/path_env_var.html). It contains paths to the directories (not files!) which contains the required binaries, libraries etc.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it, now pointing to directory not file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> export PATH=/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++:$PATH

you should add directory to PATH not path to file, in your case it is `/usr/bin`,
but because of `/usr/bin` is already in your PATH you can skip this step.

> Where qmake.conf file is located and how it should look for armhf debian wheezy platform?

Look at `mkspecs/linux-arm-gnueabi-g++/` in qt source directory, your qmake.conf should looks like it, you can just modify this file to point to your compiler.

Comment: is my compiler located in /usr/bin?

Comment: if you don't know where your cross compiler why you set your PATH like this `export PATH=/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++` ?

Comment: Ok, stupid question by me. So I need to change paths to my cross compiler in that qmake.conf which is located at mkspecs/linux-arm-gnueabi-g++?

Comment: Or create new one base on content of mkspecs/linux-arm-gnueabi-g++, this is up to you

Answer (score 0):

After a week of trying to configure arm qt cross-compiler on my Debian 7 Wheezy, I decided to try to follow [these steps](http://exploringbeaglebone.com/chapter11/) on Ubuntu 14.04, and everything went as expected! So, don't lose your time playing with Debian Wheezy host machine, try with newest Ubuntu distribution and save your time!